# Confusion with flat functors

Tags: category-theory

Let $F: C \to E$ be a functor, where $C$ is small and $E$ is complete and cocomplete. Recall that $F$ is called [representably flat](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flat+functor#representable_flatness) if one (hence any) of the following equivalent conditions hold:

**Fact: The following are equivalent:**

1. For every $e \in E$, the category $(e \downarrow F)^{op}$ is filtered.
2. For every $e \in E$, the functor $Hom(e,F): C \to Set$ is flat (in the sense that $Elts(Hom(e,F): C \to Set)^{op}$ is filtered.
3. For every $e \in E$, the left Kan extension of $Hom(e,F): C \to Set$ along the Yoneda embedding is a functor $Psh(C) \to Set$ which preserves finite limits.
4. The left Kan extension of $F: C \to E$ along the Yoneda embedding is a functor $Psh(C) \to E$ which preserves finite limits.

I am in the following quandary: I believe the proofs I've read showing that the above conditions are equivalent. And yet it seems there is a counterexample.

**"Counterexample?"**

Take $C = \{0,1\}$ to be the discrete category with two objects, $E = Psh(\{0,1\})$ to be the corresponding presheaf category, and take $F: \{0,1\} \to Psh(\{0,1\})$ to be the Yoneda embedding. Then

- The left Kan extension along Yoneda of $F$ is the identity functor $Psh(\{0,1\}) \to Psh(\{0,1\})$, which preserves finite limits, so that (4) is satisfied.

But

- In (1)/(2), take $e = \emptyset$ to be the initial object (i.e the empty presheaf). The functor $Hom(\emptyset,F): \{0,1\} \to Set$ is the constant functor at 1. (The opposite of) its category of elements is equivalent to $\{0,1\}$ again, which is *not* filtered, so (1)/(2) is *not* satisfied.

So unfortunately, this is one of those questions where my question is:

**Question:** Where am I screwing up here?

Comment: It seems you have shown that (4) is not equivalent to (1)-(2)-(3). Indeed, in the nLab article you cite, the closest analogue of (4) is instead about the left Kan extension functor $\textbf{Psh}(\mathcal{C}) \to \textbf{Psh}(\mathcal{E})$, and $\mathcal{E}$ is required to be small, not complete.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, of course you must be right. This means that even though $Hom(e,F)$ preserves finite limits for _all_ $e \in Psh(E)$ (not just representable $e$, nevertheless, $Elts Hom(e,F)$ is _not_ necessarily cofiltered if $e$ is not representable... weird! And it means that there must be some extra subtlety to Diaconescu's theorem characterizing geometric morphisms in terms of sites, because there the codomain is not a presheaf category...

Comment: The correct version of "flat" for the purposes of geometric morphisms is "internally flat". Rewriting "internally flat" in terms of sites gives a definition that subsumes "representably flat".

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, thanks. I guess I had the impression that "internally flat", once unwound from internal logic, was basically _stated_ as "representably-flat + respects covers", but given that "representably-flat" actually refers explicitly to representables (as I failed to understand before, and which you can't really do in internal logic), it must be a bit more subtle than that.

Comment: If you care to write an answer -- I dunno what it would say, maybe just "answered in the comments" would suffice, I'd gladly accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that (4) is not equivalent to (1)-(2)-(3). Indeed, in the nLab article you cite, the closest analogue of (4) is instead about the left Kan extension functor $\textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{C}) \to \textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{E})$, and $\mathcal{E}$ is required to be small, not complete.

For the purposes of understanding geometric morphisms $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are sites, the correct notion of "flat" is "covering-flat", and a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is covering-flat if and only if the left Kan extension $\textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{C}) \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{D})$ preserves finite limits.
(To get a functor $\textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{C}) \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{D})$, we require $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ to be cover-preserving.)